# how to use asp.net id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

How to overwrite html code to asp.net code for jquery?

HTML is:

```
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
<span id="showResult"></span>
```

Jquery is:

```
$('#test').keyup(function(e){
var s = $(this).val();
var ss = s.slice(-1); 
var result = '';
if(ss.search(/[^\x00-\x7E]/) != -1) result = 'fa'; else result = 'en';
$('#showResult').html(result);
});
```

Up Code Worked!

But Use With Asp.net Don't Work:

Aspx is:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMessege"></asp:TextBox>
<span id="showResult"></span>
```

Jquery is:

```
$('#<%= txtMessege.ClientID %>').keyup(function () {                
var s = $(this).val();
var ss = s.slice(-1); 
var result = '';
if (ss.search(/[^\x00-\x7E]/) != -1) result = 'fa'; else result = 'en';
$('#showResult').html(result);
});
```

Comment: I haven't worked in asp.net that much. but if you right click on your textbox in Chrome or Firefox and click inspect element you should get the correct ID of that textBox. I don't think '#<%= txtMessege.ClientID %>' is the correct ID try $('#txtMessege'). Or as I said Inspect Element.

Comment: Read this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @user3694013 does your function have a parameter or not? "function(e)" ?

Comment: Dawood Awan: Id in Client said is :"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtMessege".But Don't Work.

Comment: Nima : Don't Work With Parameter e Or Without Parameter!

Comment: Then use `$("input[id*=txtMessege]").keyup..`

Comment: '<%= txtMessege.ClientID %>' is the correct ID to use. Is this javascript embedded in your ASPX page? Because you cant get the clientID in an external javascript file.